# How to store user data in node webkit(nw.js) desktop app for login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, desktop-application, node-webkit, nw.js

I want to create a login desktop app based on node webkit. I see a tutorial using a module called diskdb to store user data locally. My question is it's local storage in each end-user's PC, right? So does this mean if someone sign up in one PC but he can't login in another PC? In real product should we use something like MongoDB hosted in cloud to store user data?

Sorry I'm pretty new to desktop apps. I think desktop app has to exchange lots of data with database in cloud, is this implemented by direct db manipulation or webservices? Or there are other ways to do it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you are right.

If you are using diskdb or sqlite than data will be stored locally. Hence user cannot login from another desktop, so in such caseyou need to use database on cloud than you might ask when will be local db helpfull, so i think it will be helpfull for data which has to be accessed frequently or repeatedly.for example when user logs in you have to fetch users details from cloud db every time user logs in and hence increases loads on server and network traffic.hence, to get rid from this overhead you can sync your localdb with server single time and hence when user logs in you will fetch user details from localdb hence saves load on server and network traffic.

example - **Skype** desktop does the same way.

Comment: Thanks for quick rely. Good to know the point of localdb usage. It really helps. Right now I know how to use MongoDB with express in web app. But when it comes to desktop app routes.js is in local, could I query/insert for db in cloud directly? I know this can't be done using Java back-end, which may need port forward.

Comment: yes you can insert data into mongodb in cloud directly